# Overriding DefaultSimilarity's scorePayload method doesn't work in pulucene

Tags: java, python, lucene, pylucene

I want to use payload in pylucene, justlike the java code in this [article](https://lucidworks.com/blog/getting-started-with-payloads/).
The python snippet is:

```
class PayloadSimilarity(PythonDefaultSimilarity):

    def scorePayload(self, docId, start, end, payload): # this never execute
        return PayloadHelper.decodeFloat(payload.bytes, end)
```

But it doesn't work. The method `scorePayload` is never invoked. Payload of word is still 1, not the value I set in the document.

The same code in java works fine:

```
class PayloadSimilarity extends DefaultSimilarity {

    @Override
    public float scorePayload(int docId, int start, int end,  BytesRef payload) {
        return PayloadHelper.decodeFloat(payload.bytes, end);
    }
}
```

I wrote the python code according to this [link](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/jcc/features.html).
Full python code is [there](https://gist.github.com/iceout/03a6334be8d7fcfaf44c)

Comment: What doesn't work? Is the output not correct? Is it throwing exceptions?

Comment: @killermonkey50 The output isn't correct. The method `scorePayload` is never invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After read the [document of jcc](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/jcc/features.html), I solved this by myself.
This problem is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426157/delimitedpayloadfilter-in-pylucene).

My solution is:

Add some code to this file `pylucene/java/org/apache/pylucene/search/similarities/PythonDefaultSimilarity.java`:

```
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;
public native float scorePayload(int docId, int start, int end, BytesRef payload);
```